Clarifying a Subtlety in Primitive Recursion on the Ordinals
I understand the Primitive Recursion on $ON$, but I only just noticed a subtle point that occurs when actually defining objects via this recursion and I would like some help getting things straight.
Take for example the recursive definition of ordinal exponentiation of some fixed ordinal $\alpha$ , where we define the class function $G: V \rightarrow V$ as $G(s) = 0$ unless $s$ is a function with domain an ordinal $\xi$ in which case:
\begin{equation} 
G(s)
\begin{cases} 
      1 & \xi = 0 \\
      s(\beta)\cdot \alpha & \xi = \beta + 1 \\
      \text{sup}_{\beta < \xi}\; s(\beta) & \xi \text{ a limit ord.}
   \end{cases}
\end{equation}
Then we obtain the desired class function $F$ such that $F(\xi) = G(F\upharpoonright \xi)$. The subltety I spoke of is that we are assuming $\text{ran}(s) \subseteq ON$ when we do ordinal multiplication in the second case above. Am I missing something, or if not, how do we get around this?
My attempt at a work around: We just go ahead and place the added restriction that $\text{ran}(s) \subseteq ON$ when defining $G$? Then we obtain the class function $F$. We know $F(0) = G(0) = 1$. Then we want to say
\begin{equation}
F(\beta + 1) = G(F \upharpoonright (\beta + 1)) = F(\beta)\cdot \alpha.
\end{equation}
But the second equality above requires by our new restriction that $\text{ran}(F \upharpoonright (\beta + 1)) \subseteq ON$ right? We argue analogously for the limit case. Therefore, for our definition to really make sense, we need to show that $\text{ran}(F) \subseteq ON$. By transfinite induction on $ON$: let $\nu$ be least ordinal such that $F(\nu) \notin ON$. Then $\nu\neq 0$. If $\nu = \beta + 1$, then $F(\xi) \in ON$ for all $\xi \leq \beta$, so that $F\upharpoonright \nu$ really is a function with range contained in $ON$. Then as we would like, we have $F(\nu) = G(F\upharpoonright \nu) = F(\beta) \cdot \alpha \in ON$. Similarly for the limit ordinal case, the supremum of set of ordinals is an ordinal. Thus we conclude that $\text{ran}(F) \subseteq ON$ and therefore, as desired we have \begin{equation} F(\beta + 1) = F(\beta) \cdot \alpha \end{equation} and \begin{equation}F(\lambda) = \text{sup}_{\beta < \lambda} F(\beta). \end{equation}
Am I overthinking this subtlety when defining $G$, and if not, does my work around justify the existence of the desired ordinal exponentiation function? Maybe this point is actually rather obvious and hence why I've never seen it explicitly written, but I felt it worth asking about as it seems to occur most of the time. Another example is when we define Beth numbers, one case of the $G$ function has $G(s) = 2^{s(\beta)}$ where $s$ is a function with domain $\beta+1$. But in this case we assume that $\text{ran}(s)$ is contained in the cardinals, or at the very least that $s(\beta)$ is a cardinal.

I agree that we should define $G(s)=0$ unless $s$ has range in $On$. Alternatively, we can use the following variant of transfinite recursion: suppose $G$ is a partial class function from $V$ to $V$ such that whenever $s$ is a function with $\text{ran}(s)\subseteq On$ we have that $G(s)$ is defined and $G(s)\in On$; then there is a unique class function $F:On\rightarrow On$ satisfying $F(\alpha)=G(F\upharpoonright\alpha)$.

Interesting, I have not seen that alternative definition before but it makes sense, thanks!
